# unexpected row when going from long to wide format with dplyr and tidyr

Tags: r

I've got a data frame (dfdat) with two categorical variables, location and employmentstatus.

I'd like to generate a data frame with the proportions of employment status for each location.

mydf_wide (achieved outcome) is almost what I'm looking for. The problem's that employmentstatus is a variable with two levels, yet there're three rows in mydf_wide. I don't understand why that is, because I'd have expected something similar to mytable (expected outcome).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
dfdat <- data.frame(location=c("GA","GA","MA","OH","RI","GA","AZ","MA","OH","RI"),employmentstatus=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1))
```

Expected outcome (table):

```
mytable <- table(dfdat$employmentstatus,dfdat$location)
mytable <- round(100*(prop.table(mytable, 2)),1)
```

Achieved outcome (df):

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- dfdat  %>%
group_by(location,employmentstatus) %>%
summarise (n = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = round((n / sum(n)*100),1))

library(tidyr)
mydf_wide <- spread(mydf, location, freq)
mydf_wide <- as.data.frame(mydf_wide)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to do a second `group_by` with 'location' to get the `sum`.  Also, instead of grouping and then creating the 'n', `count` function can be used

```
dfdat %>%
    count(location, employmentstatus) %>%
    group_by(location) %>% 
    mutate(n = round(100*n/sum(n), 2)) %>%
    spread(location, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  employmentstatus    AZ    GA    MA    OH    RI
#*            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1                1   100 66.67    50    50   100
#2                2     0 33.33    50    50     0
```

---

If we are using the OP's code, then remove the 'n' column and then do the `spread`

```
dfdat %>%
    group_by(location,employmentstatus) %>%
    summarise (n = n())  %>%
    mutate(freq = round((n / sum(n)*100),1)) %>% 
    select(-n) %>%
    spread(location, freq, fill =0)
```

or update the 'n' column with the output of `round` and then `spread`.  An extra column in 'n' made sure that the combinations exist in the dataset